# DuplicateMemberException play framework mongodb module

Tags: mongodb, playframework

I get this error on starting play application. Im using Play 1.2.4 and Mongo 1.3 module.

```
`Oops: DuplicateMemberException

An unexpected error occured caused by exception DuplicateMemberException: duplicate method: getCollectionName in models.MongoShapes

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.modules.mongo.MongoPlugin@2d7cec96 on models.MongoShapes
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:511)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:165)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:429)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:505)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:618)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.DuplicateMemberException: duplicate method: getCollectionName in models.MongoShapes
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.testExistingMethod(ClassFile.java:593)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.addMethod(ClassFile.java:577)
    at javassist.CtClassType.addMethod(CtClassType.java:1235)
    at play.modules.mongo.MongoEnhancer.enhanceMongoEntity(MongoEnhancer.java:69)
    at play.modules.mongo.MongoEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(MongoEnhancer.java:35)
    at play.modules.mongo.MongoPlugin.enhance(MongoPlugin.java:17)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:506)
    ... 7 more
```

---

My class looks like

```
@MongoEntity
public class MongoShapes extends MongoModel{
String someComment;
}
```

Comment: Honestly I strong recommend you try to use PlayMorphia plugin to replace Mongodb plugin. check it out at: http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your project include mongo module more than once. How did you declare mongo module? don't declare it in both applicaiton.conf and dependencies.yml.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. And Ill use your advice to use morphia.